# Copied variable change the original one

Tags: android, kotlin

i don't understand why with this code I get the original object `orderToDetail` changed

```
var a = with(requireActivity() as MainActivity) { orderToDetail }
a?.note = "test"
var b = with(requireActivity() as MainActivity) { orderToDetail }
```

I know I can fix this problem calling `copy()`, but I would like to understand why the `note` field gets changed in `orderToDetail` (before there was something else written, now it's "test") if I change it in the `a` variable

Comment: Because you are setting `a` to reference the exact same object as the `orderToDetail` variable. You are not copying it.

Comment: So when i do var a = <object> i'm getting a reference, and not a new object?

Comment: `I know I can fix this problem calling copy()` why ? what does copy do.... :)

Comment: @giordy16 Yes. The only way to create a new object is to call a constructor. That is what `copy` does. Doing `var a = orderToDetail` does not call a constructor.